# Geodesate vertices extraction

Tags: graphics3d, polyhedra

I'm not sure if this function is deprecated, but for some reason I find very little information about it.

I use `Geodesate` to create an icosahedral grid:

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"];
Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 1, {0, 0, 0}, 1, 0]
```

which I then want to extract the vertices (and faces) of so I can do other things with them. But it does not seem to be possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
faces = Cases[
    Normal@Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 2, {0, 0, 0}, 1],
    _Polygon, Infinity
 ];

vertices = Flatten[faces /. Polygon[vertices_] -> vertices, 1] // DeleteDuplicates;
```

For instance:

```
vertices // N
```

> {{0., 0., 1.}, {0.16246, 0.5, 0.850651}, {-0.425325, 0.309017, 
>     0.850651}, {-0.262866, 0.809017, 0.525731}, {-0.723607, 0.525731, 
>     0.447214}, {0.276393, 0.850651, 0.447214}, {-0.425325, -0.309017, 
>     0.850651}, {-0.850651, 0., 0.525731}, {-0.723607, -0.525731, 
>     0.447214}, {0.16246, -0.5, 0.850651}, {-0.262866, -0.809017, 
>     0.525731}, {0.276393, -0.850651, 0.447214}, {0.525731, 0., 
>     0.850651}, {0.688191, -0.5, 0.525731}, {0.894427, 0., 
>     0.447214}, {0.688191, 0.5, 
>     0.525731}, {0.723607, -0.525731, -0.447214}, {0.262866, -0.809017, \
>   -0.525731}, {0.425325, -0.309017, -0.850651}, {-0.16246, -0.5, \
>   -0.850651}, {0., 
>     0., -1.}, {-0.276393, -0.850651, -0.447214}, {0.723607, 
>     0.525731, -0.447214}, {0.850651, 0., -0.525731}, {0.425325, 
>     0.309017, -0.850651}, {-0.276393, 0.850651, -0.447214}, {0.262866, 
>     0.809017, -0.525731}, {-0.16246, 0.5, -0.850651}, {-0.894427, 
>     0., -0.447214}, {-0.688191, 0.5, -0.525731}, {-0.525731, 
>     0., -0.850651}, {-0.688191, -0.5, -0.525731}, {0., 1., 
>     0.}, {-0.587785, 0.809017, 0.}, {-0.951057, 0.309017, 
>     0.}, {-0.951057, -0.309017, 0.}, {-0.587785, -0.809017, 
>     0.}, {0., -1., 0.}, {0.587785, -0.809017, 0.}, {0.951057, -0.309017,
>      0.}, {0.951057, 0.309017, 0.}, {0.587785, 0.809017, 0.}}

Answer (score 1):

Since the polyhedron is in fact represented as a `GraphicsComplex[]` object, there's an even easier method to extract the vertices:

```
Needs["PolyhedronOperations`"];
vertices = First[Cases[Geodesate[PolyhedronData["Icosahedron"], 2, {0, 0, 0}, 1], 
                       GraphicsComplex[pts_, rest__] :> pts, ∞]] // RootReduce;
```

The `RootReduce[]` simplifies the exact coordinates returned; if you don't need the exact coordinates, replace it with `N[]`.